# Real orthogonal matrices with fixed entry value has zero Haar-measure?

Tags: real-analysis, matrices, measure-theory, lie-groups, topological-groups

Consider the set of real orthogonal matrices of size $n \times n$ such that one entry, say $a_{i,j}$ for fixed $i$ and $j$, satisfies $a_{i,j}=0$. Has this set zero Haar-measure? A simple proof, in affirmative (which I believe) or negative case, would be appreciated. Many Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can actually show that

$$G_{ij} = \{ A \in O(n) : a_{ij} = 0\}$$

is a smooth submanifolds in $O(n)$. In particular it has zero Haar measure.

To see this, let $F: O(n) \to \mathbb R$ be defined by $F(A) = a_{ij}$. Then $G_{ij } = F^{-1}(0)$. To show that $G_{ij}$ is smooth, it suffices to check that $0$ is a regular value of $F$.

Now let $A\in G_{ij}$. We have

$$T_AO(n) = \{V \in M_n(\mathbb R): V+V^T = 0\}$$

(see the comment below) and $DF_A :T_A O(n)  \to \mathbb R$, where

$$DF_A(V) = (AV)_{ij}.$$

(Here $(\cdot)_{ij}$ is the $(i, j)$ entry of the matrix)

Next we need to check $DF_A$ is nonzero for all $A\in G_{ij}$. Now as $A \in O(n)$, there is $j_0\neq j$ so that $a_{ij_0}\neq 0$. Now let $V$ be the matrix so that $V_{j_0 j } =1$, $V_{j j_0} = -1$ and $V_{ij} = 0$ for all other entries. Thus $V\in T_A O(n)$ and

$$DF_A(V) = (AV)_{ij} = \sum_k a_{ik}V_{kj} = a_{i j_0} \neq 0.$$

**Remark**
The above construction actually shows that 
$$G_{ij, c} = \{A \in O(n): a_{ij} = c\}$$
is a submanifold of $O(n)$ when $|c|\le 1$: When $|c|<1$, the same arguement works as we are still able to pick that $j_0$. When $|c| = 1$, $G_{ij, c}$ is actually a copy of $O(n-1)$, thus is also a smooth submanifold.

**Further Remark**
As $O(n)$ is a smooth Lie group, the Haar measure $\mu$ is given by a Riemannian metric. As a result, under any local coordinate $U$ of $O(n)$ with coordinate function $(x^1, \cdots, x^m)$, we have $\mu = G dx^1\cdots dx^m$, where $G$ is a positive smooth function on $U$. Thus $\mu$ and the standard Lebesgue measure $dx^1\cdots dx^m$ are absolutely continuous to each other. This shows, in particular, that any smooth submanifold $M$ in $O(n)$ with dimension strictly less than that $O(n)$ has zero Haar measure, as one can always find a local coordinate $U$ so that $U \cap M = \{x_1= \cdots x_k= 0\}$, where $k$ is the codimension of $M$.

For your second question, in general a tangent plane of a manifold $M$ at $x$ is given by all curves $\gamma : I \to M$ so that $\gamma(0) = x$, with the identification $\gamma'(0) \in T_xM$. Now the manifold is $O(n)$ and $A\in O(n)$. Thus all curves in $O(n)$ passing through $A$ is given by $AB(t)$, where $B(t)$ is a curve in $O(n)$ passing through $I$. Now as $B^*B = I$, differentiating this with respect to $t$ and then restrict to $t=0$ gives $\dot B^* + \dot B = 0\}$. Thus

$$T_AO(n) = \{A V: V^* + V = 0\}.$$

Comment: I'm not sure if this matters (in fact, I don't think it affects your overall argument) , but  I don't think you can describe $T_A O(n)$ as you suggest.  Certainly, if $A = I$, you are right.  But I think in general, you have $T_A O(n) = \{AV: V + V^t = 0\}$.  Said another way, one should have $T_A O(n) = (d_I L_A) T_I O(n)$ where $L_A:O(n)\rightarrow O(n)$ denotes left multiplication.

Comment: @JasonDeVito : Actually I tried to write that (and that is more accurate) but I realize that then $D_AF$ would be written $D_AF (AV)$ instead of $D_A F(V)$, so at the end I just use a little abuse of notations.

Comment: Fair enough.  You've got the $+1$ from me.  Sorry to be a bother.

Comment: @JohnMa Nice answer John

Comment: Many Thanks. 2 Comments: 1) A classical  reference for the statement that a lower dimensional manifold has measure zero would be nice. I have some, but a classical one would be appreciated.  2) The expression for the tangent space is not clear for the ones that did study pure math. long ago, or at least for me. If this follow directly from "epsilon anaylsis", writing down a direct calculation would be nice.

Comment: I've added some remarks, please have a look. @Harald

Comment: Dear John, very nice. Thank you very much for your complete answer.